# using mips instructions

Tags: mips

If a thirty-two bit word can represent a MIPS instruction. How can we tell if that instruction is of type R, J, or I?

I'm having a hard time understanding these  concepts, I think the opcodes might be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically MIPS instructions have an opcode stored in the most significant 6 bits which specify the format of the following bits. In particular, R-type instructions always have an opcode of 000000 (with the instruction functionality then further specified by the 6 least significant bits.

[MIPS Instruction Coding](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/spimsal/talref.html)